# 12 bit strings with more zeros than ones

Tags: combinatorics

I'm trying to solve how many twelve bit strings have more zeros than ones. Can someone sanity check my method please?

C(12,5) = 792 +

C(12,4) = 495 +

C(12,3) = 220 +

C(12,2) = 66 +

C(12,1) = 12 +

C(12,0) = 1 =

1586 ?

Comment: Assuming that the zeroes are indistinguishable, then yes, your method is right.

Comment: @Newb: That's surely so obvious as not to be worth stating! But if you _do_ think it worthwhile, then what about the ones? Don't they have to be indistinguishable too?

Comment: Correct. A trick to avoid calculating so many binomials is to see that the result is equal to $\frac{1}{2}\left(2^{12} - {12\choose 6}\right)$ since $2^{12} = \sum_{i=0}^{12}{12\choose i} = 2\sum_{i=0}^5 {12\choose i} + {12\choose 6}$

Answer (score 1):

Your method is correct (apart from the way you write it down; as written, it reads as $C(12,5)=792+C(12,4)=\ldots=1=1586$, but clearly $C(12,5)\ne 792+C(12,4)$, … and $1\ne1586$), but unnecessarily complicated. A simpler way is as follows:

There are three types of 12 bit strings:

- Those with more zeroes than ones.
- Those with more ones than zeroes.
- Those with the same number of zeroes and ones.

Obviously there are $2^{12}=4096$ 12 bit strings in total. Also, the number of strings of the first two types is equal, as you get one by bit-flipping the other. Finally, the last class has $\binom{12}{6}=924$ strings.

Therefore the first class (more zeroes than ones) has $(4096-924)/2 = 1586$ elements.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this method is correct:

$${12 \choose 5} + {12 \choose 4} + {12 \choose 3} + {12 \choose 2}+ {12 \choose 1}+ {12 \choose 0}=1586$$ As I am sure you know, this works because you have found the number of combinations where there are $5$ zeroes and the rest are ones, then the case where there  are four zeroes, three zeros, two zeros, one zero.

In the alternative form, the above can be constructed using standard derangement procedure, where the total number of characters in the string, and all of their permutations is divided by how many of each character is repeated with all of their permutations.
$$\frac{12!}{7!5!}+\frac{12!}{8!4!}+\frac{12!}{9!3!}+\frac{12!}{10!2!}+\frac{12!}{11!1!}+\frac{12!}{12!0!}$$

Which is of course the same as expanding out your expression.